# EJS load ejs files into layout.ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I got a default layout.ejs file where I compile header , footer etc.
layout.js. Now i want to output the page content stored in 3 different files (1. homepage, 2. artists, 3. contact formular). When the page /homepage is called up, the file homepage.ejs should be read in and displayed (for the other ones, see above).
How can I check which URL is requested or is there another way to do this

layout.ejs

```
<%- include('../partials/default/head') %>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation Top -->
    <%- include('../partials/default/navigation') %>

    <!-- Page Content -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <%- include('../partials/default/footer') %>
    <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

router

```
const
    express = require('express'),
    defaultController = require('../controllers/defaultController');

const router = express.Router();    // create different routes

// Middleware to all routes in default
router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {

    req.app.locals.layout = 'default';
    next();
})


// index routes
router.route('/')
    .get(defaultController.index)

router.route('/artists')
    .get(defaultController.artists)

router.route('/contact')
    .get(defaultController.contact)

module.exports = router;
```

controller

```
module.exports = {
    index: (req, res) => {
        res.render('default/index'); 
    },

    artists: (req,res) => {
        res.render('default/artists');
    },

    contact: (req,res) => {
        res.render('default/contact');
    },
```

in my app.js I did:

```
app.use('/',require('./routes/defaultRoutes'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layouts/default');
})
app.use('/',require('./routes/adminRoutes'));

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layouts/admin');
})
```

to implement the routes. But now the index (homepage) only shows the navigation and footer and /artists and /contact only their content, not the partials
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.ejs file add `<%- body %>` where you want the other page content to display, I'm assuming you'd want it right under `<!-- Page Content -->`